# Representing a 2D composite function through a matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a certain 2D matrix F, representing a mathematical function F(x,y), where x and y are both 1D vectors.

So, F(x,y) can be visualized through the following code:

surf(x,y,F)

Now, let's consider the other two vectors:

a = -atan(u,v),
b = asin(v)

How can I get a 2D matrix of the function F vs a,b?

If possible, I'd like to get such a matrix without for loops (i.e. using vectors) or interpolation, in order to get good performances. If it is not possible, any solution is good.

Answer (score 0):

You want to expand the 1-D inputs describing the gridded range of each independent variable into a 2-D mesh, at which point you can evaluate functions over the 2-D domain described by the mesh using elementwise operations:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html